# Windows Form. Limit User input to a certain range

Tags: c#

I am creating a windows form program for class and I am trying to limit input for a 'weight' textbox from 1-1000. I got the user input to parse to a double but some reason the error message I created will not popup at the right time as intended. (The error message will popup only if I enter digits passed 5 digits... so I can enter 2222 or 10000 without an error)

```
private void Weight_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
var sourceValue = Weight.Text;
double doubleValue;
if (double.TryParse(sourceValue, out doubleValue))
{
    if (doubleValue > 1000 )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot be greater than 1000");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use a [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) control for this task?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My teacher requires me to use user input.

Comment: Could you explain in which event do you call this code?

Comment: You need to show more code; when that code runs is very important (ie, what event handler it is in). Also, NumericUpDown, strictly speaking, is still user input (though not *string* input)....

Comment: Okay thanks! I edited it. I put it in KeyPress. Yeah.. sorry.. he wanted a string input.

Comment: Move this code in the TextChanged event

Comment: why are you using double when you are entering Integers use the debugger and you will see that `entering 2222` the MessageBox.Show because it's `put double will be `2222.0` you should learn to use the debugger in all due respect also I do not see how you can enter 2222 or 10000` without any errors based on your current logic

Comment: The problem is caused by the fact that when you receive the KeyPress event the new char entered is not part of the control text.

Comment: @Steve that's correct now that I see the updated Event which is the wrong event to begin with.. should be on the OnLeave event personally but the current one the OP has is incorrect..

Comment: I agree, the complexity to handle correctly this event is great (the copy/paste mechanics will destroy any logic in this code) however the KeyPress or KeyDown events allows to reject the char typed (e.Handled = true;) and give an immediate error message. It depends by the accuracy required.

Comment: @Steve A NumericUpDown for something that can go that high?  Personally, I just trap the textchanged and turn the background pink if the value is out of range, or yellow if it's out of range but that might simply be needed as part of the input.  (ie, acceptable is 100-1000, I would make 0-99 yellow, not pink.)  (One would think red would be the right color but that doesn't have enough contrast for me so I lighten it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using KeyPress you should use TextChanged event
because if you use keypress the new char is not part of the control text yet.

```
private void inputTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var inputTextBox = sender as TextBox;
            var sourceValue = inputTextBox.Text;
            double doubleValue;
            if (double.TryParse(sourceValue, out doubleValue))
            {
                if (doubleValue > 1000)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot be greater than 1000");
                }
            }
        }
```